# BIGQUERY An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed Error: 80038528

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pivot, unnest

I am trying to install a function. I don't understand what the problem is. I can install correctly when:

1. I delete the pivot
2. I use the Table and not the `unnest` only (so from the table, `unnest(a)`)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `dataset.function_naming` (a ARRAY<STRUCT<ROW_ID STRING, KEY STRING, VALUE STRING>>, id_one STRING, id_two STRING, start_date DATE, end_date DATE) RETURNS INT64 
AS (
    with tmp1 as (
            select ROW_ID,X,Y,Z,W
            from 
            (
                select prop.ROW_ID,prop.KEY, prop.VALUE
                from unnest(a) prop
            where prop.KEY in ('X','Y','Z','W')
            )
            
            PIVOT
                (
                    MAX(VALUE) 
                    FOR  UPPER(KEY) in('X','Y','Z','W')
                ) as PIVOT
        )

select case when X is not null then 1,
            when Y is not null then 2,
            when Z is not null then 2,
            when W is not null then 2
       else 0
from tmp1
);
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Hi, could you please add some sample data. i.e, input tables, the query you are using this function and what you want to achieve using this function  (i.e output table)

Comment: Hi, the issue is not for code or source table, but i have this issue when i try to install on BQ. So i pasted this code on my editor, BQ return me this issue: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 80038528

Answer (score 0):

There are few minor issues I see in your code.

- missing extra `(...)` around function body
- extra commas (`,`) within case statement

So, try below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `dataset.function_naming` (
    a ARRAY<STRUCT<ROW_ID STRING, KEY STRING, VALUE STRING>>, 
    id_one STRING, 
    id_two STRING, 
    start_date DATE, 
    end_date DATE
) RETURNS INT64 
AS ((
    with tmp1 as (
            select ROW_ID,X,Y,Z,W
            from 
            (
                select prop.ROW_ID,prop.KEY, prop.VALUE
                from unnest(a) prop
            where prop.KEY in ('X','Y','Z','W')
            )
            
            PIVOT
                (
                    MAX(VALUE) 
                    FOR  UPPER(KEY) in('X','Y','Z','W')
                ) as PIVOT
        )

select case when X is not null then 1
            when Y is not null then 2
            when Z is not null then 2
            when W is not null then 2
       else 0
       end 
from tmp1
));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem remains. If i replace the source with 'from Table, unnest(Table.p) + PIVOT' works. Very strange. Probably a question of allocation memory?!

Comment: your original code had some syntax issues - so I thought it was a problem that to be fixed. anyway - i tested with some simplified data and it worked for me :o)

Comment: ah frustrating. I can only think that it is a problem of allocated resources. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seams there is an internal issue when using `pivots` and the `unnest` on the array. You can use the following, that executes the same logic, and also, create an case on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/), as a BigQuery issue with Google cloud Support.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `<dataset>.function_naming` (
    a ARRAY<STRUCT<ROW_ID STRING, KEY STRING, VALUE STRING>>, 
    id_one STRING, 
    id_two STRING, 
    start_date DATE, 
    end_date DATE
) RETURNS INT64 
AS (( WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN KEY="X" THEN 1
      WHEN KEY="Y" THEN 2
      WHEN KEY="Z" THEN 2
      WHEN KEY="W" THEN 2
    ELSE
    0
  END
    teste_column
 #-- FROM ( SELECT UPPER(prop.KEY) KEY, MAX(prop.VALUE) VALUE FROM -- following your query patern, but not really necessary
  FROM ( SELECT UPPER(prop.KEY) KEY  FROM
      UNNEST(a) prop
    WHERE
      UPPER(key) IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W')
    GROUP BY key )
  ORDER BY teste_column DESC LIMIT 1 )
SELECT * FROM tmp
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 teste_column
FROM (SELECT 1)
LEFT JOIN tmp
ON FALSE
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tmp)
));

#--- Testing the function:
select `<project>.<dataset>.function_naming`([STRUCT("1" AS ROW_ID, "x" AS KEY, "10"AS VALUE), STRUCT("1" AS ROW_ID, "x" AS KEY, "20"AS VALUE), STRUCT("1" AS ROW_ID, "w" AS KEY, "20"AS VALUE), STRUCT("1" AS ROW_ID, "y" AS KEY, "20"AS VALUE)], "1", "2", "2022-12-10", "2022-12-10")
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but the code you posted doesn't do what I want.
I need the VALUE of the associated KEYs.
To replace the PIVOT, I would have to write some code that I don't like. Example: max (case when KEY = 'X' then value else null). 
I don't want to use MAX

Comment: In this case, I recommend you to open an issue on issue tracker related to this behavior on the function creation.